# Resampling Event DataFrame to 10 mints interval and counting events

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, python-datetime

I have a pandas dataframe which shows some information about some events taking place. It is basicall like this

```
Timestamp   Event Code  Prev Event Code State
2018-01-01T06:45:04.691 0   138 1
2018-01-01T06:44:33.678 138 0   21
2017-12-31T06:32:06.691 0   138 21
2017-12-31T06:31:39.687 138 0   21
2017-12-30T06:19:20.688 0   138 1
```

I want to resample this dataframe such that the timestamp is 10 mint seperated and the events count that occured in that 10 mint interval. I want something like this as output

```
Timestamp   0_count 138_count
fifth 10 min    2   2
fourth 10 min   3   0
third 10 min    5   0
second 10 min   1   1
first 10 min    0   2
```

I have just given a place holder time stamp not the actual output in the column of `Timestamp`. 10 mint seprated Timestamp should be there actually.

I don't have any idea how to approach this problem. I think there have to be some efficient methods available rather than some bunch on complex looping and codes in `Pandas`.

In order to re-produce the sample dataframe this code can be used.

```
event_df = pd.DataFrame()

event_df['Timestamp'] = ['2018-01-01T06:45:04.691', '2018-01-01T06:44:33.678',
       '2017-12-31T06:32:06.691', '2017-12-31T06:31:39.687',
       '2017-12-30T06:19:20.688']
event_df['Event Code'] = [  0, 138,   0, 138,   0]
event_df['Prev Event Code'] = [138,   0, 138,   0, 138]
event_df['State'] = [ 1, 21, 21, 21,  1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the timestamp as the dataframe index:

```
event_df.index = pd.to_datetime(event_df.Timestamp)
```

Now, you can resample:

```
count_138 = (event_df['Event Code']==138).astype(int)\
                                         .resample('10 min').sum()
count_0 = (event_df['Event Code']==0).astype(int)\
                                     .resample('10 min').sum()
```

And combine the results, if desired:

```
pd.DataFrame({'count_0': count_0, 'count_138': count_138})
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Manual checking the results is a tedious task btw